# Can I change the getenv 's return value?

Tags: c, environment-variables

I want to know what exactly will happened if I change the memory return from `getenv`

I know  this is not a good code. I know `setenv` by the way.

Like:

```
char *new_path = "/home/user/dev/myTry1";
char *path = getenv("PATH");// assume there is : PATH=/home/user/dev/myTry
//now *path = "/home/user/dev/myTry" 
memcpy(path,new_path,strlen(new_path)+1);
```

Is this a undefined behavior ? Or just a wrong code?

I tried it and no error or segmentation fault happened.

Comment: `getenv` will return a string containing the valueof the designated `env`-variable. Nothing happens when you manipulate the return value.

Comment: @bash.d: he's overwriting it with a longer string though which is almost certainly bad news

Comment: I thought it was about harming the `env`... In that particular case it is dangerous

Comment: @PaulR Is it matter about longer or shorter string?

Comment: @LidongGuo It's 1. that the docs forbid it, so you shouldn't do it under any circumstances; 2. you don't know the length of the internal static buffer, so you risk buffer overruns anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3 Just curious ~

Comment: Useful rule of thumb: if you don't own something then don't mess with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. From the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/getenv.html):

> Conforming applications are required not to modify environ directly, but to use only the functions described here to manipulate the process environment as an abstract object.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong code with undefined behavior.  I.e. you are not nannied.

Comment: what *nannied* means?

Comment: Sorry for that.  Comes from "nanny".  Roughly, it means "supervised" or "monitored".  But it's very colloquial.